# Is there a good pattern for retrieving network data only if it is not in the Store

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, ngrx

In my application, there are many `Item` records, so I load them as needed into my `@ngrx` store. If an `Item` is already in the store, I `select()` it so I don't have to make another network request. Is there a better pattern than the one I came up with?

### My Facade Service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ItemFacade {
  private readonly store = inject(Store);

  /**
   * @description blocks actions until the network request is complete
   */
  private readonly ready$ = this.store
    .select(selectLoading)
    .pipe(filter((loading) => !loading));

  /**
   * @description gets an item from the store. If it's not there, it will load it
   */
  getItem(itemId: string): Observable<Item> {

    // pessimistic request for the item will not be executed if it's already in the store
    this.store.dispatch(itemAtn.loadItem({ id: itemId }));

    return this.store.select(selectItem(itemId)).pipe(
      switchMap((stored) =>
        stored
          ? of(stored)
          : this.ready$.pipe(
              switchMap(() => this.store.select(selectItem(itemId))),
              filter((item): item is Item => !!item)
            )
      ),
      first()
    );
  }

  async getItems(ids: string[]): Promise<Item[]> {
    return await Promise.all(ids.map((id) => lastValueFrom(this.getItem(id))));
  }
}
```

### My Effect

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemEffects {
  private readonly actions$ = inject(Actions);
  private readonly store = inject(Store);
  private readonly itemService = inject(ItemService);

  /**
   * @description load the item from the server if it's not already in the store
   * and then set the loading flag to false
   */
  loadItem$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(itemAtn.loadItem),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectedAllItems)),
      // only load the item if it's not already in the store
      filter(([{ id }, items]) => !items[id]),
      concatMap(([{ id }]) => this.itemService.getItem$(id).pipe(
        map((item) => itemAtn.loadItemSuccess({ item })),
        catchError(() => of(itemAtn.loadItemFailure({ id })))
      )),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Facades are as amazing as they are "dangerous" IMO. And this is a perfect example why. Let me explain:

IMO a facade should stick to 2 and only 2 goals:

- **Hide the details of the data retention logic**. Whether you use ngrx, ngxs or other stores, it shouldn't matter to the consumer. All the consumer wants to be aware of is the type of data it'll get, not which library is doing it
- For asynchronous data, **combine bits of the store (using selectors) with other observables**, that aren't part of the store and therefore cannot be used in selectors. An example of this would be if you need to mix up your store data with a timer for example. The timer part would come directly from the facade

On the contrary, what shouldn't be done in a facade (for what seems to be a readonly method): Side effects. You can have methods that trigger side effects (to dispatch an action for example). But as a general rule of thumb I'd never do a side effect in a method that's here to get data.

For this use case, I'd strongly recommend to take advantage of [router-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store). You could then, based on the current route, trigger the loading of your data from an effect (and of course if needs to be triggered by other kind of events it could be done as well, like on click, etc).

Comment: Clearly, I need to improve my understanding of the boundaries of responsibility within the Facade pattern, but what I'm really looking for is feedback on (or examples) related to the underlying logic - regardless of the name that I give to the service.

Comment: I think I did cover this as well with the router-store. Can you be more specific if you expect anything else more than that? Really once you understand you can bind the URL state to the store, it unlocks so many possibilities. I'd advise you to dig in the URL I've shared in my original post to learn more about the router store

Comment: Determining what event triggers the need for an item is not my issue. I'd like to know of a more elegant way to check the store first and then hit the API only if needed. I feel like there must be a cleaner pattern than the messy logic above.

Comment: I don't think it'll ever be cleaner this way. It'll have a flow that isn't giving you much control. For example, what if you've got 10 observables that subscribe at the same time to it? Do you trigger the request 10 times? Do you concat? Well you don't know because you have no idea who subscribed to it and therefore you won't be able to tweak the behavior in a fine grained way. Instead if you listen from an effect to all the events that should trigger this, based on the event you have full control of what to do